# fiware spagobi Cockpit send parameter on url? its possible?

Tags: rest, api, fiware, spagobi

In my app, i have an iframe like this:

```
<iframe src="http://spagobi-server/SpagoBICockpitEngine/api/1.0/pages/execute?user_id=biadmin&password=biadmin&document=1"></iframe>
```

with this, i can embed the cockpit number 1 in my web. Thats ok, but problem is that datasource of this cockpit require a parameter called "manufacturer_id".

I try with:

```
<iframe src="http://spagobi-server/SpagoBICockpitEngine/api/1.0/pages/execute?user_id=biadmin&password=biadmin&document=1&manufacturer_id=13"></iframe>
```

Error:
[image: manufacturer Error]

my dataset seems like this:
[image: dataset cockpit]

Anyone do something like this? Or is a bad way?

Answer (score 0):

there is a more elegant way to integrate SpagoBI analyses in your web site, that is using the JavaScript API. You can see documentation in [here](http://spagobi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/JS/README/index.html). As you can see, you can inject a SpagoBI analisys providing parameters. As an example, using the injectDocument method:

```
         Sbi.sdk.api.injectDocument({
            documentLabel: 'RPT_WAREHOUSE_PROF'
            , executionRole: '/spagobi/user'
            , parameters: {warehouse_id: 19}
            , target: 'targetDiv'
            , height: '500px'
            , width: '800px'
            , iframe: {
                style: 'border: 0px;'
            }
        });
```

As you can see, this method is asking for a particular analyses (specified by "documentLabel" with certain parameters).

Hope this helps